# Excel ceiling function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, decimal.js

How to write Excel CEILING(number, significance) function in JavaScript or in decimal.js

**CEILING(10,3) = 12**  round up to nearest 3

**CEILING(36,7) = 42**  round up to nearest 7

**CEILING(560,100) = 600**  round up to nearest 100

**CEILING(6.36,0.05) = 6.40** round up to nearest 0.05

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```js
    function ceiling(number, significance) {
      return Math.ceil(number / significance) * significance;
    }

    window.onload = ()=> {
      console.log(ceiling(10, 3));
      console.log(ceiling(36, 7));
      console.log(ceiling(560, 100));
      console.log(ceiling(6.36, 0.05));
    };
```

Comment: Answers like these, while solving the problem, sadly also encourage more such zero-effort, "give me code" questions.

Comment: @Vasan Got it. I'm a newbie here, and that's not going to happen again. Sorry for that.

Comment: Let's mention some Excel's `Floor` function equivalent. `return Math.floor(number / significance) * significance;`

Comment: I found this to be very helpful, thank you!