# CEILING fnc in Excel in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, ceil

CEILING in Excel `=CEILING(E2,6)/60` for calculating legal billable hours in 6 min increments from minutes (1 min = 0.1, 5 min = 0.1, 7 min = 0.2 etc) when transposed to JS with the CEIL function as:
`var legal = Math.ceil(total_time, 6) / 6 where total_time is (date_end - date_start) / 60000 and date_end and date_start field values` in ms does not work when values are for eg. 2 min --> 0.2

Inputed values do not provide CEILING in 6 min increments as in Excel, other than values such as `30 min = 0.5`

Comment: Sorry, it's really unclear what you asking here.  Could you give some example data, and expected output, it might help clarify what your trying to do.   ps.  6 min is 6 * 1000 * 60 = 360000, and not 60000

Comment: Also `Math.ceil` does not have a second argument,you will need to multiply and divide by 6 to have the same as Excell.   eg.  `Math.ceil(n * 6) / 6`

Comment: function ceiling(number, significance) {
      return Math.ceil(number / significance) * significance;
} from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262842/excel-ceiling-function-in-javascript

Comment: Output expected: 1-6 = .1, 7-12 = .2, 13-18 = .3, 19-24 = .4, 25-30 = .5, 31-36 = .6, 37-42 = .7, 43-48 = .8, 49-54 = .9, 55-60 = 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Answer: return Math.ceil(n/6.0) / 10;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).